# How to get full Gallery Image URL Path using Magento?

Tags: php, image, magento

I have a code, it diplays product sku, product name, product image full path, but not showing gallery images full path, only display the gallery images file names, but i want to display gallery full path also, so how can i solve this one, can any one tell me this answer?

```
Product SKU:HGCL
product name:Earring03
product image url:http://example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/0/0003_3.jpg

Gallery images not showing the full paths, only image names, i want to display full path.
    /0/0/0003_3.jpg
    /v/c/vcm_s_kf_repr_658x790_28.jpg



<pre>
    <?php
    $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
    foreach($product_collection as $product) {
    $product_id = $product->getId();
    $full_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $product_sku = $full_product->getSku();
    $product_name = $full_product->getName();
    $product_url = $full_product->getProductUrl();
    $product_image_url = $full_product->getImageUrl();
    $product_image_url_gallery = $full_product->getMediaGallery();
    echo "Product SKU:".$product_sku; echo "<br/>";
    echo "product name:".$product_name; echo "<br/>";
    echo "product image url:".$product_image_url; echo "<br/>";

      for($i=0;$i<count($product_image_url_gallery);$i++)
      {  
      echo $product_image_url_gallery['images'][$i]['file']; echo "<br/>";

      }
      echo "-------------------------------------------------------"; echo "<br/>";

    }
    ?>
    </pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your updated code to get all gallery images with URL:

```
$categories = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories();

foreach($categories as $category) {

$categoryId = $category->getId();
$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection();

  foreach($product_collection as $product) {

      $product_id = $product->getId();
      $full_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
      $product_sku = $full_product->getSku();
      $product_name = $full_product->getName();
      $product_url = $full_product->getProductUrl();
      $product_image_url = $full_product->getImageUrl();
      $product_image_url_gallery = $full_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
      echo "Product SKU:".$product_sku; echo "<br/>";
      echo "product name:".$product_name; echo "<br/>";
      echo "product image url:".$product_image_url; echo "<br/>";


      foreach ($product_image_url_gallery as $image) {
        echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($full_product, 'image', $image->getFile()).'<br>';
      }     

      echo "-------------------------------------------------------"; echo "<br/>";

   }
}
```

Hope this help !!

Comment: thx a lot, but it displays only $categoryId = 10; but i want to display all categories.?

Comment: I just tested this for one category in my case. You can use all category for loop on the above

Comment: Ya ofcourse, but how to get all categories in magento, i dont know, but i tried to many ways, could u pls help me?

Comment: above my code, automatically display all category products, i didn't write any loop for $categoryId

Comment: Could you help me @Pankaj Pareek

Comment: Please check my updated answer. If it will work please accept and upvote so that other will get benefit too